# How many numbers are between $1$ and $9999$ in this case?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

How many natural numbers between $1$ and $9999$ have the sum of the digits:

$a)$ equal to $9$.

$b)$ equal to $16$

My atempt:
 So for $a)$, I did $\dbinom {9+4-1} {4-1} = 220$
 For $b)$, I calculated the total solution just like in the first case and I got $969$.
Now, since the digits are between $0$ and $9$, I have to take away the number of solutions between $10-16$. Let's say that $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are the digits.
So if one of them is $10$ then the sum of the remaining three is 6 and the number of solutions is: $\dbinom {4} {1} \cdot \dbinom {6+3-1} {3}$. 
I did the exact same thing for the cases where one of them is $11, 12, 13, 14, 15$ or $16$. I add them and got $336$.
The final solution for me is: $969-336=633$.

Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried? Please edit your question to include your thoughts on the problem and any attempt you might have had.

Comment: Well how many one digit numbers $a$ are there there $a = 9$.  How many two digit numbers $10a + b$ are there where $a+b=9$. How many three digit numbers $100a +10b + c$ are there where $a+b+c=9$.  And how many four digit numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to the first question is correct.  However, your answer to the second question is not.  Let's see why.

> How many natural numbers between $1$ and $9999$ have digit sum $16$?

By appending leading zeros to a number with fewer than four digits, we can express each positive integer less than $10,000$ as a four-digit string.  For instance, the number $17$ is represented by $0017$.  Thus, if we let $x_i$ represent the digit in the $i$th position, the number of positive integers less than $10,000$ that have digit sum $16$ is the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 16 \tag{1}$$
in the nonnegative integers subject to the restrictions that $x_i \leq 9$ for $1 \leq i \leq 4$.

A particular solution of equation 1 corresponds to the placement of $4 - 1 = 3$ addition signs in a row of $16$ ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 1 + + 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 3$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 5$, $x_4 = 8$.   The number of solutions of equation 1 in the nonnegative integers is the number of ways we can place three  addition signs in a row of $16$ ones, which is 
$$\binom{16 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{19}{3}$$
since we must choose which three of the $19$ positions required for $16$ ones and $3$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

From these, we must subtract those cases in which one or more of the $x_i$'s exceeds $9$.  At most one $x_i$ can exceed $9$ since $2 \cdot 10 = 20 > 16$.

Suppose $x_1 > 9$. Then $x_1' = x_1 - 10$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $x_1' + 10$ for $x_1$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
x_1' + 10 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 & = 16\\
x_1' + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 & = 6
\end{align*}
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with 
$$\binom{6 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{9}{3}$$
solutions.

By symmetry, there are an equal number of solutions in which $x_i > 9$ for each $i$ satisfying $1 \leq i \leq 4$.  Hence, the number of solutions of equation 1 in which no $x_i$ exceeds $9$ is 
$$\binom{19}{3} - \binom{4}{1}\binom{9}{3}$$
which is equal to the number of positive integers less than $10,000$ with digit sum $16$.

**What error did you make?**

You tried to subtract off the number of solutions in which one of the variables equals $10$.  Suppose that variable is $x_4$.  Then 
\begin{align*}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + 10 & = 16\\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 & = 6
\end{align*}
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with 
$$\binom{6 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{8}{2}$$ 
solutions.  By symmetry, there are 
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{2}$$
solutions in which a variable equals $10$.

By similar argument, there are
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{7}{2}$$
solutions of equation 1 in which a variable equals $11$,
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{6}{2}$$
solutions of equation 1 in which a variable equals $12$,
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2}$$
solutions of equation 1 in which a variable equals $13$,
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{2}$$
solutions of equation 1 in which a variable equals $14$,
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}$$
solutions of equation 1 in which a variable equals $15$, and
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{2}$$
solutions of equation 1 in which a variable equals $16$.

Hence, the number of positive integers less than $10,000$ with digit sum $16$ is 
$$\binom{19}{3} - \binom{4}{1}\left[\binom{8}{2} + \binom{7}{2} + \binom{6}{2} + \binom{5}{2} + \binom{4}{2} + \binom{3}{2} + \binom{2}{2}\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

Stars and bars.

In the first case, you have 9 stars to allocate over 4 bins, or 9 stars and 3 bars.

${9+3\choose 3}$

In the second case you have 16 stars and 3 bars and you cannot but more than 9 stars in any one bin.

${19\choose3} - 4{10\choose 3}$